# disable selections/background colour when single click blank area

Tags: python, pyqt5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD3l3.png)I'm currently writing a GUI using QTableWidget to analyze CSV files. It seems like by default I can single click a cell and select it, but there's no way to deselect it(I guess). Also, I have a  function that allows me to highlight the cell I desire by searching. Now I want a feature where I can single click the blank area and deselect/disable the highlighted cell. By blank are, I mean the area outside the main QtableWidget.

I know I need to use a MousePressEvent, and the logic will be

```
if # mouse click on the blank area and # there's at least one cell selected:
   # deselect the cell

elif  #mouse click on the blank area and # there's at least one cell highlightended:
    # disable the background colour
```

I don't know how to write the specific code

Here is how I implement the search and highlighting cell code:

```
def findNmber(self):  # find the desire number and highlighten the cell
    if self.tabWidget.currentIndex() is 0:
            itemFound = False
            item = self.searchLoanNum.toPlainText()
            for rowIndex in range(self.inLoanTable.rowCount()):
                tbItem = self.inLoanTable.item(rowIndex,1)
                if tbItem.text() == item:
                   itemFound = True
                   self.inLoanTable.item(rowIndex,1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255,124,124))
            if itemFound == False:
                QMessageBox.warning(self,"Error","No Match",QMessageBox.Ok)
```

The whole class

```
class mainForm(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.search.clicked.connect(self.findNmber)
        self.search_2.clicked.connect(self.findNmber)
```

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1303, 972)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 1201, 931))
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.South)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.inLons = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.inLons.setObjectName("inLons")
        self.searchLoanNum = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.inLons)
        self.searchLoanNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(980, 10, 141, 31))
        self.searchLoanNum.setObjectName("searchLoanNum")
        self.search = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.search.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1120, 10, 71, 31))
        self.search.setObjectName("search")
        self.loanNumberS = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.inLons)
        self.loanNumberS.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(930, 10, 41, 31))
        self.loanNumberS.setObjectName("loanNumberS")
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(970, 860, 101, 41))
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1080, 860, 101, 41))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.createNewColumn_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.createNewColumn_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 161, 41))
        self.createNewColumn_1.setObjectName("createNewColumn_1")
        self.createNewLoan = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.createNewLoan.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 20, 161, 41))
        self.createNewLoan.setObjectName("createNewLoan")
        self.openFile = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.openFile.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 20, 161, 41))
        self.openFile.setObjectName("openFile")
        self.generateNum = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.inLons)
        self.generateNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 20, 161, 41))
        self.generateNum.setObjectName("generateNum")
        self.inLoanTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.inLons)
        self.inLoanTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 1171, 781))
        self.inLoanTable.setObjectName("inLoanTable")
        self.inLoanTable.setColumnCount(0)
        self.inLoanTable.setRowCount(0)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.inLons, "")
       
     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Herbarium Assistant"))
        self.search.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        self.loanNumberS.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Loan #"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.createNewColumn_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "create a new column"))
        self.createNewLoan.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "create a new loan"))
        self.openFile.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "open file"))
        self.generateNum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "generate #"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.inLons), _translate("MainWindow", "IN-LOANS"))
        self.createNewColumn_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "create a new column"))
        self.createNewGift.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "create a new gift"))
        self.openFile_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "open file"))
        self.generateNum_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "generate #"))
        self.giftNumS.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Gift #"))
        self.search_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search"))
        self.save_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.exit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "blank area"? In any case, your `findNumber` function does *not* select the item, it only changes its background; item selection (and highlighting) is completely different from setting an item background. The answer to your question might change a lot, so please specify *exactly* what you want to do.

Comment: sorry for my confusing description. Yes my findNumber doesn't select items, it search certain text and change its background colour, nothing wrong with this one. I post the code simply for reference. By blank are, I mean the area outside the main QtableWidget.

Comment: so by the deafult, when I populate a CSV file I can select any cells, and it turns its coulor into blue, but I cannot change it back. I want deselect the cell(change its coulor to normal) when I single click the area outside the QTableWidget. As I have the findNumber function which also change certain cell background colour(it will change into pink), I want the 'single click blank area' function change my "pink cell' to normal as well. I want these tow things, but they both need to be achieved by the ' single click blank area' function.

Comment: I add my GUI pic hope it clears my question

Comment: So, by "click on blank area" you mean "click anywhere outside the table"?

Comment: yup that's correct

Comment: Then, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because the answer might depend on your code.

Comment: Please, read the link about the MRE, the example has to be minimal **AND** *reproducible*. It really doesn't matter how you fill up the table (the contents of the table are not the issue here), we need to know how the UI is structured.

Comment: I updated new one

Comment: How would that help us? "Reproducible" means that we should be able to copy and paste your code, and then run it to see what it does. We are still missing the `Ui_MainWindow` code for the ui.

Comment: updated. It's part of the code but I think it can be copied and tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to catch all mouse button events that happen outside a specific widget, you should install an event filter on the application, check whenever mouse button events happen and ensure that the widget at that position is not the one you're looking for.
Consider that many classes use children widgets (QTableWidget is one of them), so you need to go through the parent structure to ensure that the clicked widget is not a children of the one you're searching.

```
class mainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.initUI()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            # ensure that the source is a QWidget descendant, and it is in this window
            if (isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QWidget) and 
                source.window() == self and source != self.inLoanTable):
                    widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.widgetAt(event.globalPos())
                    while widget:
                        if widget == self.inLoanTable:
                            break
                        widget = widget.parent()
                    else:
                        # the widget or its parent(s) are not the table, proceed
                        self.resetBackgrounds()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def resetBackgrounds(self):
        model = self.inLoanTable.model()
        for row in range(self.inLoanTable.rowCount()):
            for column in range(self.inLoanTable.columnCount()):
                index = model.index(row, column)
                # check whether the index has a background set
                if index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole):
                    # if it has, reset it
                    model.setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)

        # clear the item selection
        self.inLoanTable.clearSelection()
```

Some important notes.

- Item selection and highlighting are two completely different and unrelated things; this must be clear to you *and* to the user.
- The behavior you're trying to achieve might be confusing to the user: why should clicking somewhere else un-highlight a cell? What's the purpose of it?
- You are not using any layout manager, all widget geometries are fixed, which is something that should be avoided almost everytime, for lots of reasons: for example, I've a screen size smaller than your UI, I had to resize the window and the result was that some widgets were not visible anymore. Set a main layout for your main window, and use sub layouts for container widgets (like QTabWidget).
- From what you wrote in the comments it appears that you're trying to implement your program by modifying a file generated from `pyuic`, which should *never* be done (nor you should try to mimic its behavior). Always keep those pyuic files intact, and use a separate one for your main script.
- When asking about a minimal reproducible example, we mean that we need to be able to copy, paste it and run it with possibly minimal (if none) modification; even after your modifications, your code is still hard to reproduce, since it's missing components (for instance, `search_2`, which wasn't needed for the purpose of this question, thus you should have not included that connection in the first place). If you don't help us, we cannot help you: don't "I think it can be copied and tested": copy and test it on your own. People here is eager to help but get also easily bored if they don't see enough efforts: if you don't provide what's required or requested, many of them will just go on, ignoring your question, leaving you without any answer.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped to solve your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on its left. It will help people find your question, and will also give some reputation points, which are good for future advancement here on SO. For future reference, I strongly suggest you to follow the guidelines about the MRE, ensure your question is correctly focused on the matter without including unnecessary things, and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions.